# How would we express in plain English the $o(x)$ in the expression $P_{2n,0,\cos}(x)=1+o(x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

The question and discussion below is based on reading the introductory chapter of the book "Asymptotic Methods in Analysis" by N.G. de Bruijn.

Reading this chapter is my attempt to understand Big-O and Little-o notation.

I have a few questions, but I will post them one by one so that each post is very specific.

The current question is, as the title states, how we would read the symbol $o(x)$ in the expression for the Taylor polynomial of order $2n$ of $\cos$ at $0$.

The book seems to state that "$=o(x)$" is to be interpreted with the $=$ as "is" and the o-symbol read as

> something that tends to zero, multiplied by

As I will explain below, I am not sure I understand this particular phrase in this context.

Let me explain the context of this question by going through the theory I learned in the book. The most relevant part is towards the end, in the section entitled "o-symbol".

**O-symbol**

The O-symbol is meant to represent the words

> something that is in absolute value less than a constant number
> times

Instead we will use it in the sense

> something that is, in absolute value, at most a constant multiple of
> the absolute value of

Now

> Let $S$ be any set. Let $f$ and $\phi$ be real functions defined on
> $S$ (they could also be complex functions, but let's leave those out).
>
> Then
>
> $$f(s)=O(\phi(s))\ \ \ \ \ (s\in S)\tag{1}$$
>
> means there is a positive number $A$ independent of $S$ such that
>
> $$|f(s)|<A|\phi(s)|, \text{ for all } s\in S\tag{2}$$
>
> In particular, if $\phi(s)\neq 0$ for all $s\in S$ then
> $\frac{f(s)}{\phi(s)}$ is bounded throughout $S$.

Sometimes we are interested in results as in $(2)$ only on parts of a set $S$.

For example, take the function $e^x-1$. It is not true that $e^x-1=O(x)$ on the set $(-\infty,\infty)$. On the set $-1<x<1$, however, it is true, and thus

$$e^x-1=O(x)\ \ \ (-1<x<1)$$

In order to facilitate the use of O-notation when it is not essential to pin down an exact interval, we can use the modified O-notation

$$f(x)=O(\phi(x))\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)\tag{3}$$

which means that there exists a number $a$ such that

$$f(x)=O(\phi(x))\ \ \ \ \ (a<x<\infty)$$

In other words, there exist numbers $a$ and $A$ such that

$$|f(x)|\leq A|\phi(x)|\text{ whenever }a<x<\infty$$

**o-symbol**

The o-symbol used, for example,  as

$$f(x)=o(\phi(x))\ \ \ \ \ (x\to\infty)$$

means that $\frac{f(x)}{\phi(x)}$ tends to $0$ when $x\to\infty$.

This is a stronger assertion than the O-symbol.

Thus, this implies that the expression $(3)$ above is true. That is, above some value, $\frac{f(x)}{\phi(x)}$ is bounded.

Notation-wise, we read the $=$ as "is" and the o-symbol is read as

> something that tends to zero, multiplied by

**I'm not sure I understand the latter.**

Take for example the function $\cos{x}$ and its Taylor polynomial.

$$P_{2n,0,\cos}(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-...+(-1)^{i}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

For any $i=1,2,3,...$ we have $\frac{x^{2i}}{x}=x^{2i-1}$.

Then $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{(-1)^ix^{2i}}{(2i)!}}{x}=0$$ and thus we can say

$$P_{2n,0,\cos}(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to 0)$$

Indeed we could say

$$P_{2n,0,\cos}(x)=1+o(x)\ \ \ \ \ (x\to 0)$$

The $o(x)$ would read something like

> the expression composed of the remaining terms in the Taylor
> polynomial is something that tends to zero, multiplied by $x$.

But shouldn't it be "divided by" instead of "multiplied by"?

Comment: Note that $o(x)=o(1)\cdot x$, so you can also say that $o(x)$ is a tend-to-zero quantity multiplied by $x$.

Comment: Okay, it is easy to see that something that is $o(1)$ tends to zero multiplied by $1$. But what if we have $o(x^2)=o(x)\cdot x$. Then the question would be how do we express $o(x^2)$? And the answer would be obtained recursively because we know that $o(x)$ is something that tends to zero (multiplied by $x$. But somehow, this doesn't get at some kind of insight that I am looking for here.

Comment: @Traincopter If I were to explain the concept to someone else, I would use plain English. Plus, I am doing an exercise here, it involves the Taylor polynomial of $\cos$. I have a more difficult problem I am working on, but I decided to express the part I don't understand with this relatively simple problem.

Comment: For any $f(x)$, $o(f(x))$ can always be explained by $o(1)\cdot f(x)$, so your case with $o(x^2)$ is $o(1)\cdot x^2$.

Comment: I prefer to say "$o(f(x)) $ is something which after division by $f(x) $ tends to $0$". Your textbook says that $o(f(x)) $ is a product of something which tends to $0$ and $f(x) $.

Answer (score 1):

The author starts section 1.3 *The $o$-symbol* with the characterisation

> The expression
> \begin{align*}
> f(x)=o(\phi(x)))\qquad\quad(x\to\infty)\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> means that $f(x)/\phi(x)$ tends to $0$ when $x\to\infty$.

This already brings in a lot of the essentials when using the $o$-symbol and it is a nice explanation when we state this in plain English. Somewhat more colloquial we could say

> The function $\phi(x)$ *dominates* $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to infinity.

Similarly we could also state the relation
\begin{align*}
\cos(x)=1+o(x)\qquad\qquad (x\to 0)\tag{2}
\end{align*}
as the function $\cos(x)-1$ is dominated by $x$ as $x$ goes to zero and we can prove this by showing
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1}{x}=0
\end{align*}

When N.G. de Bruijns introduces the phrase

- ... and *$o$* is to read as *something that tends to zero, multiplied by* ...

he could possibly have meant: multiplied by $1/\phi(x)$. After all, the explanation in (1) by de Bruijn is clear and there's no doubt about its meaning.

**Notes:**

- In fact I think de Bruijn's introduction of *big Oh* and *little oh* notation is pedagogically sound especially when considering his introduction of the $L(n)$ operator with the meaning: *something that is less than $n$*. He introduces this operator $L$ to indicate with a familiar relation the slight abuse of the $=$ symbol and its asymmetry when we use it with *big Oh* and *little oh* notation.
- D.E. Knuth appreciates this approach since he explicitly cites de Bruijn in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
  where he uses the $L$ operator as introductory helpful mean in section 9.2 *O Notation*.
- If you want to explain a friend the concept of *big Oh* and *little Oh* notation, a nice little review in proper understanding might be
  \begin{align*}
  \sin(x) - x &=o(x)\qquad&(x\to 0)&&\\
  \sin(x) - x &=o(x^2)\qquad&(x\to 0)&&\\
  \sin(x) - x &\ne o(x^3)\qquad&(x\to 0)&&\\
  \sin(x) - x &=O(x^3)\qquad&(x\to 0)&&\\
  \end{align*}

Comment: Just to confirm then, to express $o(f(x))$ in plain English, de Bruijn's use of the expression "multiplied by" is either a typo (to be replaced by "divided by") or is meant to be succeeded by $1/f(x)$. Either way he should have written this part of the book a little better, huh.

Comment: @evianpring: I agree. :-)

Comment: @evianpring: Many thanks for granting the bounty.